# focus() is not working in my html form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont how it is working in the snippet! :( 
I checked so many times. In my output, the password field is getting focused even when the phone number is wrong.

```js
function checkmatch() {
  var name = $("#username").val();
  var address = $("#address").val();
  var email = $("#emailid").val();
  var mobile = $("#phonenum").val();
  var password = $("#newPwd").val();
  var cnfirmPassword = $("#confirmPwd").val();

  if (password != cnfirmPassword) {
    alert("Passwords do not match.");
    $("#newPwd").val('').focus();
    $("#confirmPwd").val('');
    return false;
  } else if ((name == null || name == "") || (address == null || address == "") || (email == null || email == "") || (mobile = null || mobile == "") || (password == null || password == "") || (cnfirmPassword == null || cnfirmPassword == "")) {
    alert("Please fill all the required fields.");
    return false;
  } else {
    /*$.ajax(
     {
      type: "POST",
      url: "assmt1.php",
      datatype: "html",
      data:  $("#fm1").serialize(),
      success: function(response)
      {
       
      }
     });
    alert("Your form has been submitted. Thank you!");*/
  }
}

function validateMobile() {
  var phoneno = $('#phonenum').val();
  var phone = document.forms["fm1"]["field4"].value;
  var phonenumber = phone.replace(/[^\d]+/g, "");
  if (phonenumber.length > 9 && phonenumber.length < 13) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Enter a valid phone number");
    $("#phonenum").val('').focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function isnumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if ((charCode > 31 && charCode < 43) || (charCode > 43 && charCode < 48) || (charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="fm1" name="myForm" method="post">
  <label>Mobile Number <input  type="text" id = "phonenum" name="field4" onkeypress="return isnumberKey(event);" onchange = "validateMobile();" /></label>
  <label>Password <input type="password" id="newPwd" name="field5" /></label>
  <label>Confirm Password <input type="password" id="confirmPwd" name="field6"/>  </label>
  <input style="cursor:pointer" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkmatch();" name="Sign Up" />
```

This is my code for phonenumber validation. I want the phonenumber field to be cleared and then focused if the validation fails.

```
if (phonenumber.length > 9 && phonenumber.length < 13) {
  return true;
} else {
  alert("Enter a valid phone number");
  $("#phonenum").val('').focus();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: oops missed. forgot about the chaining.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? When does this JavaScript code execute? What happens if / when this executes?

Comment: @i-- I think that will not clear the field

Comment: `$("#phonenum").focus(function() { this.value = ""; });`

Comment: what is the issue? any error? did the value get clear? did it actually get it the alert?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that would just register an event handler that clears the field on focus. That is **not** what OP wants

Comment: @Phil I have used onchange(function) in my html code to perform phonenumber validation

Comment: Works fine over here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/9a4ee6pc/

Comment: @Se0ng11 No error.. but the phone number field is not getting focused.

Comment: @Pranava that doesn't really answer **any** of my questions

Comment: Just a sidebar: I believe it is bad practice to clear the field of anything other than default values. Let the user edit rather than having to type it in all over again.

Comment: @Phil do you want me to attach my html part?

Comment: @Pranava that would be critical information required to help solve your problem, so "yes". Even better would be a JSFiddle example demonstrating the problem

Comment: Your code works correctly in the question above

Comment: @Phil yes.. but in my actual form the focus is going to the next field.. On what constraints the `focus()` function will not work?

Comment: @Phil Anyways `focus()` is working with the **password** field as you can see in the snippet.

Comment: It works for the mobile field too

Comment: @Phil Yeah.. But in my form it is not..

Comment: Check your form element ID's. My guess is that you have some duplicates